# Class Members and Using Statements

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose a class is defined:

```
class TestClass
{
    MemoryStream s = new MemorySteam();

    void DoStuff()
    {
        using (s = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

What happens to `s` when the using statement exits scope?

Edit:
Will there be a problem using `s` in a different method?

Edit 2: Will there be an unreferenced object left undisposed from the first instantiation of MemoryStream?

Comment: In addition to the various "it's dispose method is called" (which are all correct), it is also worth noting that it becomes eligible for garbage collection (because it is not referenced further on in the function).

Comment: @ChrisShain I am not 100% without running tests, but I do not believe that is a guarantee. You could implement your dispose improperly and leave events wired up. This would keep it from being GC'd

Comment: I just updated my answer to answer your edit FYI

Comment: @JustinPihony that's correct- you could also reference it from a thread started within the scope, which would have the same effect.  Both are big no-no's, since you don't generally want to be holding a reference to a disposed object, and in the vast majority of the cases (including the example), it isn't an issue.

Comment: Aren't you creating two 's' objects at different scopes? One is at the class level, and the other is local. So only the local 's' is disposed? What happens to the class-level 's'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method is called. (Note that it must implement the IDisposable interface so it can guarantee that Dispose is available)

[The MSDN reference is pretty good IMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Phil Haack also wrote an in depth article on this 7 years ago.](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/11/18/ACloserLookAtDisposePattern.aspx)

**UPDATE TO YOUR EDIT**

Once a method has had its dispose method called it will throw an exception if you try to use it outside of the scope of the method. So, yes it would be bad to reference it outside of the using. [To be precise, it will throw an ObjectDisposedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

It's Dispose method is invoked.

[using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Dispose method is called on objet in order to clean this object

We call using in order to clean non managed object, because they are not cleaned by GC

GC don't have informations about non managed object so developper must clean

Comment: Dispose doesn't destroy the object. Dispose allows the object to clean-up any unmanaged resources.

Comment: i'am sorry Brian i'am french so i don't know english language subtilities, thank you for remark , in future i will speak very good